# Execution Timed Out

Tags: c#, время

Ошибка во времени исполнения кода. Код, может, и кривой, но крашиться, по-идее, не должен. Прошу помочь кто может.

Вот задание:

Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will have volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a volume of 1^3.
You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?
The parameter of the function findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb) will be an integer m and you have to return the integer n such as n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m if such a n exists or -1 if there is no such n.

Вот код:

```
public class ASum { 
    public static long findNb(long m) {
    int n = 2;
    int result = 0;
    while(n<m)
    {
        result = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            result += i*i*i;
        }
        if(result == m) return n;
        else n++;
     }
     return -1;
    }
}
```

Вот ошибка:

Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)

P.S. Спасибо за ответы. Но вопрос именно в том, почему этот код - неверный, а не какой код лучше. Пожалуйста, кто знает, - ответьте

Answer (score 1):

Я решу эту задачу за 0 циклов.

```
public static long findNb(long m) {
    long root = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Sqrt(m));
    if (root * root != m) // не является суммой кубов последовательных чисел
    { 
        return -1; 
    }
    long d = 1 + 8*root;
    long n = (-1 + Math.Sqrt(d)) / 2;

    if (Math.Pow(0.5 * n * (n+1), 2) != m)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

*PS. На с# пишу впервые в жизни, возможно наврал с квадратным корнем и переводом double в long.*

**Пояснение**

Сумма кубов числового ряда от 1 до n равна (0.5 * n * (n+1)) ^ 2. Поэтому в первой строчке беру целую часть квадратного корня из `m` и потом проверяю, равен ли квадрат этого корня числу `m`. Если нет, то входное число не является суммой кубов.

Дальше просто решаю квадратное уравнение, выведенное из первой формулы:

`(0.5 * n * (n+1)) ^ 2 = m` -> `n^2 + n - 2*m = 0`

*PPS. Сейчас собразил, что если `m` будет квадрат, который не является суммой кубов (например, 49), то функция выдаст неверный результат. Так что нужно добавить еще одну проверку:*

```
if (Math.Pow(0.5 * n * (n+1), 2) != m)
{
    return -1;
}
```

*Но теперь надо ещё специально обрабатывать ситуацию m = 0.*

Comment: можете пояснить, что и зачем вы делаете в этом коде?

Comment: @tym32167 добавил пояснение

Comment: @tym32167 *"Если надо объяснять, то не надо объяснять."*

Answer (score 0):

*Я знаю - отвечаю.*

Ваш код неправильный, потому что Вы сравниваете "яблоки" с "апельсинами". Здесь

```
while(n<m)
```

`m` - общее число маленьких кубиков в здании, а `n` - количество кубов, представляющих собой ступени в этом "мавзолее".

---

```
long result = 0;
for (int i = 1; result < m; i++)
{
  result += i*i*i;
  if (result == m)
    return i;
}
return -1;
```

Без никакого двойного цикла.

```js
function findCubes(m) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 1; result < m; i++) {
    result += i * i * i;
    if (result == m)
      return i;
  }
  console.log(i, result);
  return -1;
}

console.log(findCubes(1 + 8 + 27 + 64 + 125 + 6 * 6 * 6 + 7 * 7 * 7));
console.log(findCubes(1000000000000));
```